# Can't add PPA using add-apt-repository: SSL support not available

Tags: python, ppa, ssl, add-apt-repository

Whenever I try to add any PPA to install any stuff, I get the following error:

```
nikunj@nikunj-DL-H61MXE-V:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 326, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 91, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 148, in urlopen
    raise ValueError('SSL support not available')
ValueError: SSL support not available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 122, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 841, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 391, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 355, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 338, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 295, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 148, in urlopen
    raise ValueError('SSL support not available')
ValueError: SSL support not available
```

Comment: You should consider using four-space indents for error messages and code.

Comment: Do you have `apt-transport-https` installed? If not, install that and try again. It would seem that "ValueError: SSL support not available" is the problem here.

Comment: any commands to install that?

Comment: Same way you install anything on Ubuntu. `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`

Comment: @nikunjbaheti have you succeeded with solution in comments above?

Comment: @SuperSluether I have the same issue. i tried your suggestion. I already had apt-transport-https installed but i still uninstalled and reinstalled it. I am using Kubuntu 18.10.

Comment: @lovesh & nikunj are you using a network proxy or VPN?

Answer (score 0):

It could be same case as this one [SSL support not available, Ubuntu 18.04, ppa repository](https://serverfault.com/q/975527/79479)

Custom/incompatible version of openssl is installed in system.

- Check current binary

  ```
  which openssl
  ```
- Check if there any copy from PPA or it is absolute

  ```
  aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ~Oppa | ~o)'
  ```
- Check if any lib installed using `pip`

  ```
  pip2 show pyOpenSSL
  ```